# Need to have my SQL Server Express from 2005 to 2008

Tags: sql-server

At this moment, I have a `SQLEXPRESS` instance running SQL Server 2005 Express, and a second instance `SQL2008` running SQL Server 2008.

I need to have my `SQLEXPRESS` instance under SQL Server 2008.

How can I proceed? Upgrading? Uninstall SQL Server 2005 Express + reinstall?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is more of a http://serverfault.com question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the name of an instance. You need to install it again, as `SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Ok I cannot change the name of an instance but can I migrate my SQLEXPRESS from 2005 to 2008? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas:

1) You can do an in-place upgrade using the installer.

2) Slower but less downtime:

- Backup all your DBs, restore them to another server, point everything to that server.
- Uninstall main instance, clean install 2008.
- Restore DBs to 2008 instance 1 by 1 and point applications to that instance 1 by 1.

Second way takes more effort but the downtime is however long it takes you to change the connection string (ie. seconds)